# HTML/Javascript whole page reloads instead of single item

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I'm new to javasript/html and am currently trying to build a site that scrambles one of a predefined words. Then displays the scrambled word and two buttons.
One button is to load a new word and the other one to display the original word. Everything seems to be working fine, instead of the "show correct word button". This is what I got so far. I deleted some of the stuff to make it nicer here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Ausgabe() {
            document.getElementById("Testerest") = WortArbeit; 

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> Wortfluessigkeit</h1>

    <script language=JavaScript type="text/javascript">


        var Wort=new Array("DRACHENZAHN");


        var rand=0; // normally random number 
        var WortArbeit = Wort[rand]; // word that gets changed
        var Laenge = Wort[rand].length; // lenght of the word
        var WortTemp = new Array([Laenge]); // word that gets scambled
        var Moeglichkeit = new Array([Laenge]); // stores position of letter

        for (var i = 0; i < Laenge ; i++) {
            WortTemp[i] = Wort[rand][i];
             Moeglichkeit[i] = i;
        }


        shuffleArray(WortTemp,Moeglichkeit);

        function shuffleArray(arr,arr2){
            for (var i = arr.length; i--;){
                var sIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var h = arr[i];
                var j = arr2[i];
                arr[i] = arr[sIndex];
                arr2[i] = arr2[sIndex];
                arr[sIndex] = h;
                arr2[sIndex] = j;
            }
            return arr;
            return arr2;
        }


        document.write(WortTemp.join(""));
        document.write("<br>");

    </script>

            <main>
<form>
    <button class="link">Neustart</button>
    <button onclick="Ausgabe" id="Testerest" >Loesung</button>
    <label>Originalwort:
        <output id="AusgabeWort"></output>
    </label>
            </main>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the originally choosen, unscrambled word to show up in the output with id=AusgabeWert, but at the moment when i click the button the whole thing loads again.

Comment: You can't `return` and then `return` again. The first `return` exits the function at that point.  If you want to return multiple values, you can use an array `return [arr, arr2]` or an object `return {arr: arr, arr2: arr2}`

Comment: I think you're missing a conditional in your `for` loop: `for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--;)`

Comment: try by adding `type` attribute of your button like-`<button type="button" onclick="Ausgabe" id="Testerest" >Loesung</button>`.

Comment: @KhairulIslam yup that helped. fixed some more and now it works.

Comment: good work, best of luck.